# Given $M=M_1(M_1+M_2-A)^{-1}M_2$ choose $M_1$ and $M_2$ so that M is associated with SSOR

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

M is given as $M=M_1(M_1+M_2-A)^{-1}M_2$, and we want M of the form $\frac{1}{\omega(2-\omega)}(D+\omega L)D^{-1}(D+\omega U)$, with $\omega \in (0,2)$ and $A=U+L+D$. I have chosen $M_1=D+\omega L, M_2=D+\omega U$, which I'm fairly certain is right. I plug them into my given M equation, and I cannot simplify the equation to the desired form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.